# Warning WEB9052: Unable to load class com.organizer.ejb.ContactsBean, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm using NetBeans 7.1 with Glassfish 3.1.2 for developing a simple Java EE 6 web application (a kind of address book). I've searched in wide about my issue on the web but without useful results.

My application uses PrimeFaces 3.2 with JSF 2.1.7.

**File ContactsBean.java**

```
package com.organizer.ejb;

import com.organizer.entity.Contact;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ContactsBean {

    private List<Contact> contacts;

    private Contact contact=new Contact();

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="PersonalOrganizerJPA")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

        @Resource
        private UserTransaction utx;

        public ContactsBean()
        {

        }

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contact c");
        contacts = (List<Contact>)query.getResultList();
        return contacts;
    }

    public void salva(ActionEvent event){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.joinTransaction();
            em.persist(contact);
            utx.commit();
            showGrowlInsMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }finally{
            em.close();
        }       
        contact=null;
    }
    public void aggiorna(ActionEvent event){

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.joinTransaction();
            em.merge(contact);
            utx.commit();
            showGrowlUpdMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }finally{
            em.close();
        }       
        contact=null;
    }
    public void elimina(ActionEvent event){

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.joinTransaction();
            Contact c = em.find(Contact.class, contact.getId());
            em.remove(c);
            utx.commit();
            this.showGrowlDelMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                showGrowlErrorMessage();
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }finally{
            em.close();
        }       
        contact=null;
    }
    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    private void showGrowlUpdMessage(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();   

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Contatto aggiornato con successo"));   


    }
    private void showGrowlInsMessage(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();   

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Contatto inserito con successo"));   


    }
    private void showGrowlDelMessage(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();   

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Contatto eliminato con successo"));   


    }
    private void showGrowlErrorMessage(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();   

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Errore", "Operazione fallita"));   


    }
}
```

**File web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/ContactsPage.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**File ContactsPage.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <p:resources />
        <style>
            form{font-size:12px;}
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <p:spacer height="10"></p:spacer>
         <p:graphicImage value="Contacts" fontName="Tahoma" fontStyle="bold" fontSize="24"/>
         <p:spacer height="10"/>
        <p:panel header="Contacts">
            <p:dataTable var="contact" value="#{contactsBean.contacts}" id="tbl"
                selection="#{contactsBean.contact}" selectionMode="single"
                update="updForm:updDisplay" onselectComplete="updDialog.show()"
                paginator="true" rows="5">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nome" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{contact.name}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Cognome" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{contact.surname}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Telefono" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{contact.telephone}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Professione" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{contact.job}" />
                </p:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">

                     <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:commandLink>
                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/excel.png" style="border:none" />
                            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="contacts"
                                pageOnly="true" />
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/pdf.png" style="border:none" />
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="contacts"
                                pageOnly="true" />
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/csv.png" style="border:none" />
                            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tbl" fileName="contacts"
                                pageOnly="true" />
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/xml.png" style="border:none" />
                            <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="tbl" fileName="contacts"
                                pageOnly="true" />
                        </h:commandLink>

                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <p:spacer height="10" />
    <h:form id="updForm">

       <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:commandButton oncomplete="newDialog.show()" value="Nuovo Contatto"
            update="newDisplay" ajax="true" />
        <p:themeSwitcher initialText="Cambia tema"></p:themeSwitcher>
       </h:panelGrid>

        <p:dialog widgetVar="updDialog" header="Contatto" width="430"
            height="220" modal="true">
            <p:outputPanel id="updDisplay">
                <h:inputHidden value="#{contactsBean.contact.id}" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.name}"></p:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Cognome" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.surname}"></p:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Telefono" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.telephone}"></p:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Professione" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.job}"></p:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Aggiorna" ajax="true"
                    actionListener="#{contactsBean.aggiorna}" update="tbl,growl"
                    onclick="updDialog.close()"></p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton value="Elimina" ajax="true"
                    actionListener="#{contactsBean.elimina}" update="tbl,growl"
                    onclick="updDialog.close()"></p:commandButton>
                        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"  /> 
            </p:outputPanel>

        </p:dialog>


    </h:form>
    <h:form>
        <p:dialog widgetVar="newDialog" header="Inserisci Contatto"
            width="430" height="220" modal="true">
            <p:outputPanel id="newDisplay">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.name}"></p:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Cognome" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.surname}"></p:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Telefono" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.telephone}"></p:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Professione" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{contactsBean.contact.job}"></p:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Salva" ajax="true"
                    actionListener="#{contactsBean.salva}" update="tbl"
                    onclick="newDialog.close()"></p:commandButton>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**And this is the warning that GlassFish give to me.**

```
Warning: WEB9052: Unable to load class com.organizer.ejb.ContactsBean, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.organizer.ejb.ContactsBean
```

**Exception stack trace.**

```
Warning: Cannot create update center Image for C:\glassfish3; Update Center functionality will not be available in Admin Console
Information: p:resources component is deprecated and has no use in PrimeFaces 2.0 as JSF 2.0 resource apis are used instead to place resources on page.
Grave: Error Rendering View[/ContactsPage.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ContactsPage.xhtml @28,31 value="#{contactsBean.contacts}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'contactsBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.isLazy(DataTable.java:968)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:191)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:61)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:185)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:108)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Edit: this is the structure of the entire application.**
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Dc4.png)

Comment: Problem solved!
The ManagedBean (ContactsBean) was located in the wrong project (now I moved it from PersonalOrganizer-ejb to PersonalOrganizer-war), but I also had to set PersonalOrganizer-war as main project instead of PersonalOrganizer in order to have a correct compiling and deployment.

Can someone explain the meaning of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you 'have' to set your project as the main project to get it to work properly, it can be a caching problem, glassfish problem or a user error. I've been working with glassfish for a while now and 20 to 30 percent of the errors come from faulty deployment/caching.